# comport read in Matlab every time specific characters are transmitted

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I have an instrument transmitting data in packets of 40 characters each time. 
Each packet includes a packet of interest (32 characters in the middle of it) that is bounded by additional four predefined characters before and after it used in to locate it.

The data is transmitted to the PC to a comport buffer. I want to read the data from it using matlab:

- Is there a way to scan the content of a buffer continuously in the background without blocking the command line?
- Is it possible to read data from the buffer as soon as a packet exists in it by finding the first and last characters that define each packet?

Comment: Which protocol are you using?

Comment: Bluetooth serial port profile (SPP)